# Superscrollorama onPin messed up my layout

Tags: jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation, gsap

I am running superscrollorama with Foundation 4 and cant figure out why my layout change and get stuck to the left onPin.

I've tried everything but it seems like upon pin, it changed my layout from relative to fixed and margin left/right auto to left: 0px and that broke my layout.

How should I go about it?

css file is here: http://wemakegreatweb.com.au/test/css/styles.css

Thanks guys in advance.

edit: Forgot to attach url :S

http://wemakegreatweb.com.au/test/index.html

I've set the main-1 div to pin, for 4000 pixels. It seems to pin okay, but as explained above, the layout breaks.

Answer (score 0):

After several more weeks experience with this plugin I have a better answer for you.

1. Try not to pin to the element you are affecting,  use containers so that you are pushing around.  So have a container wrapping the main-1 so that you aren't playing with your container so much.
2. Width issues can be problematic with this plugin,  I was not able to get a good margin: 0 auto; to work in several places I had to do a max-width or width of 100% to make sure it would look right.